# How to center only one element in a column of 5 elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, row, center

I have 5 elements in a Column, and I make them cross in start,
and I need to add another element 'Text' in the center of the column,
So How do I make my Text centered in the entire Column, and the rest elements to the right start?

Answer (score 2):

In `column` one element wrap with `Align` widget

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('in start'), 
            Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Row(children: [ Icon(), Text() ] )),
            Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("test")),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
          ],
        ),
```

Ouput:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, this is my code:
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                      Text('in start'),
                       Row( //make it in center
                             children: [
                                  Icon(),
                                   Text()
]

Comment: wrap your row with `align` like given examle

Comment: it works for Text Widget but doesn't work for Row, i need it for Row, I edit my Question and add my screens please have a look

Comment: you can try with in row `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,`

Comment: pass `alignment: Alignment.center,` here is useless, this property by default is `Alignment.center`, moreover there is `Center` widget

Comment: great observation @Nagual

Answer (score 0):

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```
 Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("start"),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("ink")),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              Text("Center"),
            ],
          ),
          Text("text "),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Can you add your full widget tree so that we can check, how many column or rows it contains. Also, can you add a diagram that include the widgets names.